# Can't open project .NET Core in Visual Studio2015 Community

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2015

My buddy sent me a project we have been working on on his computer. We are both using Visual Studio Community 2015 Community. When i try to open the project on mine, it says it is incompatible and "The application is not installed." I doesn't seem like I'm getting any other information about what's causing the problem.

EDIT: I found a "Migration Report" that gives me the following error:

src\CarDealerV2\CarDealerV2.xproj: The application which this project type is  based on was not found.

Comment: your buddy used the project type that looks like you don't have installed on your machine. Ask what type of project it is (web, mobile) and install what's needed.

Comment: @PawełŁukasik He created an "ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core)" which I can also do on my own computer. So I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: same version installed? they change a lot in ASP.NET Core APIs these days.

Comment: VS 2015 does *not* include tooling for Core. The tooling is added as an extension

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2015 doesn't include tooling for .NET Core. You need to install the .NET Core tools separately. The tools require Update 3 so make sure you install it before installing the tools.

The requirements and links can be found at the [.NET Core site](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowsvs2015).

Comment: Not 100% correct though. Visual Studio 2015 does ship with some preview bits of .NET Core, but of course now everyone should download the latest from the site you mentioned.